# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED Login.js:11 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch at handleSubmit (Login.js:11:1)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, web-deployment, mern

> I'm getting this error i dont know why

```
const handleSubmit = async (e)=>{
            e.preventDefault(); 
                //API call
                const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login`, {
                  method: 'POST',
                  headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                  },
                  body: JSON.stringify({email: credentials.email, password: credentials.password})
                });
                const json = await response.json();
                console.log(json);
                if(json.success){
                    //save the auth token and redirect
                    localStorage.setItem('token',json.authtoken);
                    navigate("/", { replace: true }); 

                }
```

In the Login component there is this function that handle the submit form

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'   

const Login = () => {
    const [credentials, setCredentials] = useState({email:"",password:""})
    let navigate = useNavigate();

        const handleSubmit = async (e)=>{
            e.preventDefault(); 
                //API call
                const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login`, {
                  method: 'POST',
                  headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                  },
                  body: JSON.stringify({email: credentials.email, password: credentials.password})
                });
                const json = await response.json();
                console.log(json);
                if(json.success){
                    //save the auth token and redirect
                    localStorage.setItem('token',json.authtoken);
                    navigate("/", { replace: true }); 

                }
                else{
                    alert("Invalid credentials")
                }
    }

    const onChange = (e)=>{
        setCredentials({...credentials,[e.target.name]:e.target.value})
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <div className="mb-3">
                    <label htmlFor="email" className="form-label">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" className="form-control" id="email" name="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" onChange={onChange} value={credentials.email}/>
                    <div id="emailHelp" className="form-text">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</div>
                </div>
                <div className="mb-3">
                    <label htmlFor="password" className="form-label">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" className="form-control" id="password" name="password" onChange={onChange} value={credentials.password}/>
                </div>
                <button type="submit"  className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login
```

Comment: You have to show your backend code

Answer (score 0):

Your fetch promise is rejected and there is not any catch block. Try to add try...catch around await fetch(...) and log an error in catch clause.